# Deploy to Azure from Github with Readonly Access

Tags: git, azure, github, deployment, continuous-integration

I would like to setup automatic deployment from a private Github repo to an Azure website. After reading through the [official tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step7) it looks like the only built-in way is to give azure full read/write access to every repo on your github account via the API.

Is there a simple way to setup azure deployment and only give read-only access to a single repo using Githubs readonly deployment keys?

Answer (score 0):

When you setup deployment from GitHub, one part of the process is to pull the source (from doc you refer to):

> Azure creates an association with the selected repository, and pulls
>   in the files from the specified branch.

But another, and most important for the CI/CD process is creation of a new [WebHook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to your repository. Setting up a Web Hook requires write permissions to the repository, thus the requirement for Read/Write.

You can also read on the [CD process in Project KUDU Wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment) (note: Azure Web Apps runs on the Project KUDU)